# Random High CPU Usage

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have noticed that Visual Studio Code randomly has a really high CPU usage.  Generally, this seems to be related to the window where I have a SQL server project.  Below is the output from `code --status` when this recently happened.  Any insights into what might be going on here?

```
code --status

Version:          Code 1.27.1 (5944e81f3c46a3938a82c701f96d7a59b074cfdc, 2018-09-06T09:14:32.385Z)
OS Version:       Darwin x64 17.7.0
CPUs:             Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz (12 x 2900)
Memory (System):  32.00GB (2.58GB free)
Load (avg):       3, 3, 3
VM:               0%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     /Users/thebitguru/Desktop/Work/Visual Studio Code/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                    enabled
                  checker_imaging:              disabled_off
                  flash_3d:                     enabled
                  flash_stage3d:                enabled
                  flash_stage3d_baseline:       enabled
                  gpu_compositing:              enabled
                  multiple_raster_threads:      enabled_on
                  native_gpu_memory_buffers:    enabled
                  rasterization:                enabled
                  video_decode:                 enabled
                  video_encode:                 enabled
                  webgl:                        enabled
                  webgl2:                       enabled

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
   87      131    4742  code main
    0      131    4743     gpu-process
    0      197    4744     window (~/golang/src/github.com/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../auth.go — proj1)
    0       98    5023       extensionHost
    0       33    5024       watcherService
    0       33    5033       searchService
   77      262    4745     window (~/Desktop/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../V20180905_4.0.18_1907.sql — db)
    0      131    5025       extensionHost
    0       98    5055         /Users/thebitguru/Desktop/Work/Visual Studio Code/code-portable-data/extensions/ms-mssql.mssql-1.4.0/sqltoolsservice/1.4.0/OSX/MicrosoftSqlToolsServiceLayer
    0       66    5026       watcherService
    0       33    5053       searchService
    0       98    5027     shared-process
    0      197    5121     window (~/Desktop/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../messages.go — proj2)
    0       98    5122       extensionHost
    0       33    5123       watcherService
    0       33    5128       searchService
Workspace Stats:
|  Window (~/Desktop/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../hermes.go — proj2)
|  Window (~/Desktop/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../V20180905_4.0.18_1907.sql — db)
|  Window (~/golang/src/github.com/...PATH_MANUALLY_REMOVED.../auth.go — proj1)
|    Folder (proj2): 35 files
|      File types: go(23) log(2) yaml(2) gitignore(1) pid(1) md(1) mod(1)
|                  sum(1) txt(1) sql(1)
|      Conf files: makefile(1)
|    Folder (db): 175 files
|      File types: sql(154) conf(7) txt(3) jar(3) DS_Store(2) gitignore(1)
|                  md(1) yml(1) cmd(1) dll(1)
|      Conf files:
|    Folder (proj1): 3846 files
|      File types: go(3057) json(126) js(118) hcl(83) md(70) scss(54) s(50)
|                  gitignore(28) yml(27) txt(24)
|      Conf files: package.json(60) makefile(6) launch.json(1)
|                  settings.json(1) tsconfig.json(1)
|      Launch Configs: go
```

Comment: In my case, it was "PHP IntelliSense" after disabling it the CPU usage is normal again.

Answer (score 46):

first you need to find which process eating your cpu, for that vscode has inbuilt process Explorer. You can find at Help => Open Process Explorer

For me the culprit is electron_node tsserver.js,
I solved it by turning on the typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition, for that you need to go Settings => Extensions => TypeScript and check the `Typescript: disable Automatic Type Acquisition`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to **Help => Open Process Explorer**

Comment: BTW. To find this setting: File > Preferences > Settings. (Or press ctrl+,) Then start to type Acqui... and it pops up.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue today.

First I removed Php intelliSese Extension and my cpu usage came down to around 25%.
Then I removed Vetur extension for Vuejs (I don't remember how or when I installed this), and now everything is running normal and cool.

Hopefully it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks. I will try disabling any PHP extensions. Unfortunately, in my case it is likely the Microsoft SQL extension that's the culprit, but I need the functionality that this extension provides :-/

Comment: I had the EXACT same problem with `PHP Intellisense`. My VS Code extension was also using more than 4 GB of RAM. At the end, after 10 minutes at 100%, I could test the PHP extension, but I was disapointed. The intellisense was unable to complete `$foo->` while the `Foo` class was declared in another file.

Comment: Almost 3 years later, Php intelliSese Extension still causing high CPU usage

Comment: PHP IntelliSese does not see much development, I have had much better luck with [PHP Intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense).

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10

I was also facing a similar problem with my VS Code. It was consuming huge amounts of power(HIGH) and also lots of CPU resources. For me, I was running a JavaScript application; So I guess, after selecting the `Typescript: disable automatic type Acquisition` it worked for me and there was a significant improvement!

Even if you observe that your laptop is getting heated abnormally while using VS Code, you should try one of the approaches mentioned by others here!

Answer (score 2):

Its probably some extension. For me it was IntelliSense. Disable them one by one to check.

Answer (score 1):

Today my Visual Studio Code was draining my CPU and this happened after I had created a big bunch of files (6GB each of which being a couple of KB). I moved the files outside the scope of the editor and everything worked fine. I guess some extension or the editor itself was having a hard time indexing the files.

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after I installed C/C++ extension in VScode. I think it is the VScode's bug. After I uninstalled this extension the high cpu problem was solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I import my whole user directory, e.g. /home/usr/ into visual code and eventually crashed my system. I resolved it by selecting specific working directory, e.g. /home/usr/Documents/work, and adding subsequent folders when needed. Then, my CPU usage back to normal

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Max TS Server Memory.

- press "F1"
- choose "Preferences: Open Settings (UI)"
- search "Max TS Server Memory"
- change to something higher like 6000 (mine was 3072)

saw here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38329

I did not want to disable TSServer because it helps with autocomplete, imports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where just typing into my JS project would cause my CPU use to skyrocket to 100% and when I stopped typing it would settle down at 12%. This was infuriating because it would cause everything else to hang, including the video player on Udemy.

So I decided to apply all the advice I found in this thread to my own issue but the issue still persisted. So I decided to disable my extensions one by one to see if that solved the issue.

Funnily enough, it was GitHub's own "[GitHub Pull Requests and Issues"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) extension that caused my issue. Disabling it dropped my CPU usage from 100% to around 40%, which was a start!

As another user mentioned, try disabling your extensions methodically to see if that alleviates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with this problem even my vs code was taking almost between 60% to 70% of CPU and also with memory usage. I have faced this problem for 1 month. I tried to reinstall another version of vs code more than 4-5 times. and also tried to disable some extensions. but nothing happened. the problem was that I had already installed a lot of extensions and added different projects to the workspace. **This works for me** when I removed unused projects folders from the workspace without disabling or uninstalling the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem but in my case whas the **PHP extension pack** for Xdebug. I have disable that package and CPU under 10% again :D

Answer (score 0):

For me, Typescript, PHP extension pack for Xdebug, C/C++ extension, PHP Intellisense are not responsible for 100% CPU usage.

I disabled all the extensions but no luck.

I found that my **Data folder of VSCode had not enough writable permission**. After correcting permission, it is fine even after enabling all the extensions.

Comment: where is the location the folder

Comment: depends on where you setup. Default for windows is %APPDATA%\Roaming\Code

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. When I turned on the live server, the CPU usage increased. Found the solution here https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/26
You need to add this to the live server settings file:

```
"liveServer.settings.NoBrowser" : true,
"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [
          "*",
          "**"
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me and I used this guy's article to narrow it down in a few mins. https://remysharp.com/2022/09/17/vs-code-using-all-of-the-cpus-and-how-to-fix-it

> Extension Bisect
>
> Open the command palette (cmd+shift+p is my mac keyboard shortcut) and
> type "bisect" for "Help: Start Extension Bisect".
>
> This then automates the entire process. It took me less than 5 minutes
> to find the extension that was causing all my headaches for months.
>
> What's going to happen is that the utility is going to disable half of
> the extensions (temporarily) and restart VS Code. In my case I was
> "lucky" enough to have the offending extension consistently spiking
> the CPU.
>
> The extension then asks if VS Code is behaving now or if it's still
> bad. Depending on your answer, it'll continue to bisect the extensions
> until (they estimate after about 8 times) you'll be left with the
> single offending extension:
>
> The bisect prompt
>
> Somehow I have 174 extensions, which with the prospect of doing this
> manually was terrifying. The extension bisect, because it's entirely
> automated, it tracks what it disabled, it tracks what the abort state
> is, and it means that it was incredibly quick to resolve.